# Basic meteor users subscription does not tally client server

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have been messing around with meteor 7.1.1.
Just need some sanity check,

So basically..

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  console.log("Count Server No: "+ Meteor.users.find().count());
  Meteor.publish("directory", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find();
  });
}
// server side results in Count Server No: 1

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("directory");
  console.log("Count Client No: " + Meteor.users.find().count());
}
// client returns Count Client No: 0
```

I have seen various tutorials and other possible routes, but there seems to be various methods to do this. If someone can point out. would be most grateful. PS hopes this helps someone.

Comment: ahhh. forgot to mention. the counts should tally client to server.

Comment: and this works... Template.content.count = function(){
        return Meteor.users.find().count();
    } // returns 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Collections on the client and server are not synchronized immediately upon subscription, but asynchronously in the background. The *subscription* objects have a function `ready()` which returns `true` if the initial batch of data has been sent to the client.

Additionally, a [subscription can take *callbacks* during definition](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe) for the `onReady` and `onError` events. For example, providing only the *onReady* handler:

```
Meteor.subscribe("directory", function () { 
    alert('Count = ' + Meteor.users.find().count());
});
```

should show the correct number of users.